# how to append a dataframe to existing partitioned table to specific partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a existing table like below

```
  create_table=""" create table tbl1 (tran int,count int) partitioned by (year string) """
spark.sql(create_table)

insert_query="insert into tbl1 partition(year='2022') values (101,500)"
spark.sql(insert_query)
```

and i create dataframe like below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from datetime import datetime
rows=[
        (1,501),
        (2,502),
        (3,503)
     ]
from pyspark.sql.types import *
myschema =StructType([
                        StructField("id",LongType(),True),\
                        StructField("count",LongType(),True)                       
                     ])
df=spark.createDataFrame(rows,myschema)
```

Now I want to append this dataframe to above table and append values to existing partition 2022.

How can i do that

Comment: can you create a temp view using the df using [`createOrReplaceTempView()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView.html) and use that to insert values from that view.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the dataframe, you could include the `year` as well, then `partitionBy` and write into the table:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').getOrCreate()

rows=[
        (1,501,'2022'),
        (2,502,'2022'),
        (3,503,'2022')
     ]
myschema =StructType([
                        StructField("id",LongType(),True),\
                        StructField("count",LongType(),True),\
                        StructField("year",StringType(),True)
                     ])
df=spark.createDataFrame(rows,myschema)

df.write.mode('append').partitionBy('year').saveAsTable('tbl1')
```

Comment: Hi 
I am getting this below error

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o158.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Dynamic partition strict mode requires at least one static partition column. To turn this off set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict


what this " Dynamic partition strict mode requires at least one static partition column. To turn this off set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict" error means?

Comment: @SurendiranBalasubramanian, trying adding these configs: `hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true, 
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict`. If this doesn't work, try altering the last line to: `df.write.mode('append').insertInto('tbl1')`.